# getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception when inserting too much data

Tags: java, android, arrays

when i am putting less data it is running fine ,but when data is bigger getting the exception ,I didn't set my array size limit ,where i am wrong?

```
   public static void readQuestions(InputStream inputStream, Context context) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] contents = line.split("-");
            String marksId = contents[0];
            String quesId = contents[1];
            String subject  = contents[2];
            String question = contents[3];

            CDataSource cDataSource=CDataSource.getInstance(context);
            cDataSource.addMidSemQuestions(new MidSemQuestions(marksId, quesId, subject, question));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my file:

```
 2-1-Cloud Computing-What are the advantages of using cloud computing?
2-2-Cloud Computing-Mention platforms which are used for large scale cloud computing?
2-3-Cloud Computing-Explain different models for deployment in cloud computing?
2-4-Cloud Computing-What is the difference in cloud computing and computing for mobiles?
2-5-Cloud Computing-How user can gain from utility computing?
```

2-6-Cloud Computing-For a transport in cloud how you can secure your data?
   2-7-Cloud Computing-What are the security aspects provided with cloud?

and traces:

```
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                          at com.example.questionbank.model.FileReader.readQuestions(FileReader.java:29)
                                                                          at com.example.questionbank.CSplashScreen.readData(CSplashScreen.java:54)
                                                                          at com.example.questionbank.CSplashScreen.onCreate(CSplashScreen.java:48)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

why it is giving error at only first time ??After that crash it is running normally.

Comment: Please post a complete stack trace from logcat.

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you add the stacktrace of the exception and an example of failing data.

Comment: Are you sure that every line of your inputstream contains suffiecient `"-"` separators?

Comment: Can you post the buffer string without the split?

Comment: show your error log

Comment: what line number?

Comment: @Ritesh  String quesId = contents[1];  here at 29

Comment: If Possible try to debug and check., if more no of lines then print the line number in console where the problem is... and check the actual file in that particular line.

Comment: @Gowrishankar  here i am changing the very first content of line ,,is here the problem

Comment: @Gowrishankar 2-39-Cloud Computing-How buffer is used to Amazon web services?
2-40-Cloud Computing-Mention what is Hypervisor in cloud computing and their types?
5-41-Cloud Computing-How does cloud computing provides on demand functionality?
5-42-Cloud Computing-What is the difference between scalability and elasticity?

Comment: Just check if the array `content` is having enough `-` to split. To check, `for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { Toast.makeText(this, content[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show }` This will display each element one by one in toast and you can get idea what was the mistake.

Comment: @Jack I am inserting too much data and the content is ok, the exception i am getting is only on first launch after that it runs as normal

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 means you are getting the error at  String quesId = contents[1]; that means you have the wrong input which causes the problem. Invoke readQuestions() method with some delay just to check for which input it makes the error.

Comment: @MdFazlaRabbiOpu i have checked the quesId seems ok, there are around 500 questions for which quesId is defined as 1.2.3.4.5.....500 ,

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] contents = line.split("-");
String marksId = contents[0];
String quesId = contents[1];
String subject  = contents[2];
String question = contents[3];
```

Check this piece of code, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown if the **contents** size is not 4 in your case.

Also the logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

clearly says the size of contents is 1 and you are trying to access at position 2, i.e. contents[1].

Put it in a try catch, if that helps.